# DropShadow QML widget in Qt6

Tags: qt, qml, qwidget, qqmlcomponent, qt6

I have a problem:
I need to use **DropShadow effect** from QGraphicalEffects (which **deleted** in qt6) in my app.

How I can do it or replace it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still [import](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt5compat-graphicaleffects-dropshadow.html) `GraphicalEffects` from the `Qt5Compat` module:

```
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects
```

However you first have to install the `Qt5Compat` module from the Qt installer, which long term might not be what you want in new code as it is going to go away eventually.

Comment: Hi JarMan, are you on the US? If you are, ping me on LinkedIn if you are interested in a new Qt/QML job opportunity. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, qt can't find qt5Compat... I need to install qt5 to use it?

Comment: Are you using Qt version 6.0? You might need to be on 6.2.

Comment: No, I using 6.2.1 qt version

Comment: Then it should be there. Are you sure you spelled it right? Here's the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtgraphicaleffects5-index.html).

Comment: Ohh, i found error: ```module "Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects" is not installed``` How i can install it?